# Password Generator Using Multiple Strings in Swift

Tags: swift, random, passwords, generator

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to create a password generator. I've created one using a single array of strings (all lowercase or all uppercase). But I want to create using multiple arrays. I'm using Swift 5.3 (Xcode 13.2.1)

```
struct ContainCharacterSelection {
    var containNumbers: Bool = true
    var containLowerCharacters: Bool = true
    var containUpperCharacters: Bool = true
    var containSpecialCharacters: Bool = true
    var containComplicatedCharacters: Bool = false
}

class PasswordGenerator {
    
    let numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    let lowerCharacters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    let upperCharacters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    let specialCharacters = ["!","\"","§","$","%","&","/","(",")","=","?","+","*","#",",",";",".",":","-","_","@","<",">"]
    let complicatedCharacters = ["^","[","]","{","}","\\","'","`","´"]

var password = ""
var passwordLenght = sliderValue
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Join an array of strings into a single string.

  ```
  let numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

  let joinedNumbers = array.joined() //joinedNumbers equals to 0123456789
  ```
- Join other arrays via the same way:

  `joinedLowerCharacters,joinedUpperCharacters.....`
- Then we concatenate these strings as a single string.

  `finalString = joinedNumbers+joinedLowerCharacters+joinedUpperCharacters+...`

Now we could generate password using the `finalString`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. This is relatively simple and does not actually check the existence of certain type of character. If you need to absolutely verify the existence of certain character type, you might have to do some weird recursion logic.

However, this should work in most of the simpler cases.

```
struct ContainCharacterSelection {
    var containNumbers: Bool = true
    var containLowerCharacters: Bool = true
    var containUpperCharacters: Bool = true
    var containSpecialCharacters: Bool = true
    var containComplicatedCharacters: Bool = false
}

class PasswordGenerator {
    
    let numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    let lowerCharacters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    let upperCharacters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    let specialCharacters = ["!","\"","§","$","%","&","/","(",")","=","?","+","*","#",",",";",".",":","-","_","@","<",">"]
    let complicatedCharacters = ["^","[","]","{","}","\\","'","`","´"]

    var password = ""
    var passwordLength = 32
    
    func generate(selections: ContainCharacterSelection) {
        
        var includedChars: [String] = [];
        if selections.containLowerCharacters {
            includedChars += lowerCharacters;
        }
        
        if selections.containUpperCharacters {
            includedChars += upperCharacters;
        }
        
        if selections.containNumbers {
            includedChars += numbers;
        }
        
        if selections.containSpecialCharacters {
            includedChars += specialCharacters
        }
        
        if selections.containComplicatedCharacters {
            includedChars += complicatedCharacters
        }
        
        includedChars.shuffle()
        
        // mind it that this could crash if your array is smaller than the passwordLength, in that case use alternative solution commented below
        self.password = includedChars[..< passwordLength].joined(separator: "")

       // let randoms = (0 ..< passwordLength)
       //             .map { _ in includedChars.randomElement() }
       //             .compactMap { $0 }
       // self.password = randoms.joined(separator: "")
    }
}


var selections = ContainCharacterSelection()
selections.containUpperCharacters = true
selections.containLowerCharacters = true
selections.containSpecialCharacters = true

let passwordGenerator = PasswordGenerator()
passwordGenerator.generate(selections: selections)
print("Password: ", passwordGenerator.password)
```

Comment: There might be a problem with this solution. Because you're using `.shuffle()`, each password will at maximum have 1 of each character. It wouldn't be possible to generate a password that would have 2 letters 'a', for example.

Comment: It all depends on the use case. This is a simple example that I had shown, this could be modified to what you would want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I think in case of a password generator you'd generally want different functionality than what you have provided. Why would you limit your password generator to use only 1 occurrence of a symbol in a password? That just reduces the entropy. (I'm not trying to attack you with these comments.)